# Unreadable value returned in VBA/ADO from SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, vba, ado, sql-server-2019

To monitor SQL Server jobs in a VBA app, I run the sp_get_composite_job_info stored procedure from the msdb database using ADO. I check the current_execution_step field once I have the results in a ADODB.Recordset. This has worked fine with SQL Server 2012 for years.

We just migrated to SQL Server 2019 and now the same code which still works on SQL Server 2012 is returning an unreadable value for the current_execution_step field.

Instead of "4 (Step Name)", I get a bunch of rectangles and squares.

If I run the same call to sp_get_composite_job_info in SSMS, I can read the current_execution_step  field just fine on both servers. It's only when I try to read that field in VBA/ADO that it's gibberish.

What's worse, I can read other fields from that same recordset just fine. It's only this one field (which just happens to be the only field I need to read) that is unreadable.

The driver I'm using in VBA is ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. But again, I use the same driver for both servers, and only 2019 has this issue.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Unfortunately  `sp_get_composite_job_info` is an undocumented procedure, so it is possible that it has changed the data type of that column.  You should also note that although VBA can use Unicode, the VBA IDE cannot display it properly so don’t be misled by the debugger in this regard.

Comment: Yeah, my first thought was that it was unicode and I read somewhere that the IDE couldn't display unicode, so I tried just displaying it in a control, but it was the same gibberish. I also tried the StrConv function to convert it from unicode, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Could be UTF-8, SQL Server supports that now but VBA would need a conversion.  Or maybe print out the hex codes and see if anybody recognizes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, the answer was as simple as going back to OLE and switching the Provider to SQLNCLI11 instead of SQLOLEDB. Since SQLNCLI11 is omnipresent, I don't have to hunt down all of the machines that might use these apps and install MSOLEDBSQL on them.

Comment: `SQLNCLI11` is not included with the OS like SQLOLEDB but is included with SQL Server 2012 and later. So you'll be ok if you only run on machines with SQL Server installed (until  you upgrade to a new SQL version that doesn't include it).

Comment: Right, I meant "omnipresent on all of the machines in question". There's probably a part of our standard IT install that includes this, which is why it's already on all of the machines.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server 2012 version of `sp_get_composite_job_info` (undocumented as @RBarryYoung mentioned) returns `current_execution_step` as `nvarchar(128)` whereas SQL Server 2019 returns `nvarchar(MAX)`.

ADO is unaware of SQL Server datatypes introduced after SQL Server 2000. Try installing the latest [MSOLEDBSQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56730) OLE DB driver (ADO is natively OLE DB) and specifying the [DataTypeCompatibility=80](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/system-requirements-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) in the connection string.

Comment: Man, I was hoping you wouldn't say that. I was going to try the new OLE provider (I was previously using SQLOLEDB in this app for 2012), but it's not present on my dev machine, nor is it safe to assume it's on any machine this app will be used on. The function this serves is minor (just displaying a bit of info to the user) and I'd rather not go through the trouble of a bunch of installs (and having to install on any machine going forward) for the sake of this minor feature. I'll test this out tomorrow either way.

Comment: Microsoft has moved to a model where SQL Server drivers are a separate download and install. The ones included with Windows (e.g. SQLOOLEDB) are just for backward compatibility with legacy applications and stuck in the SQL 2000 world. This does make it a pain but the upside is you can move new driver versions at your own cadence rather than rely on the OS version. You might consider PowerShell instead of VBA for the long term.